# How to use __getitem__ on a class while keep typing/mypy happy

Tags: python, mypy

I am modelling a problem where it doesn't make sense to have instantations of a class -- in this case the periodic table.
I want to be able to index the periodic table with an int and get the associated element (from the atomic number; the element objects are stored as class variables).
I can do this easily with metaclasses, but mypy doesn't like this.
Here is my approach:

```py
class PeriodicTableBase(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, x: int) -> int:
        return x

class PeriodicTable(metaclass=PeriodicTableBase):
    pass

a = PeriodicTable[1]
```

and after finding PEP560:

```py
class PeriodicTable:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, x: int) -> int:
        return x

a = PeriodicTable[1]
```

Mypy gives the same error for both of these (presumably because they collide with the way generic types are defined):

```
Typing.py:9: error: "PeriodicTable" expects no type arguments, but 1 given
Typing.py:9: error: Invalid type: try using Literal[1] instead?
```

Of course they both function at runtime.

Is there a way I can do this cleanly whilst keeping mypy happy?

Comment: Why make `PeriodicTable` a class instead of an instance of a `dict`? This looks like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @chepner The `__getitem__` can return the same element from multiple keys, some of which need to be parsed from strings. I just put in the simple `int` case here to keep the code small.

Comment: You can return the same element from multiple keys with a `dict` as well.

Comment: Even if you want a class, creating a class with only one instance isn't really any different from creating a metaclass used to create only one class. (In fact, it's *exactly* the same, as `PeriodicTable` is the only instance of `PeriodicTableBase`. You may as well dispense with all the metaclass baggage and define a regular class.)

Comment: Python annotation system and by extend mypy *do not* understand metaclasses. The ``some_class[thingy]`` syntax is exclusively used for generics, and various tools (e.g. mypy, but also others) will likely hardcode it.

Comment: @chepner That makes sense. Some elements will need quite a few entries, due to old baggage, but yes, you're right, it's easier to just to create a single instance of the class with all the elements defined normally.